# Vue watch unexpectedly called twice

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

**udpate #2:** It is not a bug, it was my own fault. I extended the `BaseComponent` by a `extend()` method as well as putting `extends: BaseComponent` into the options. I thought I needed both, but `extends: BaseComponent` in the options seems to be enough.
So the double "extend" has apparently duplicated the watcher which lead to the strange behavior I documented in my question.

**update:** I found out what causes this problem: The watcher seems to be duplicated, because it's in a `BaseComponent` which is extended by the `Component` which is used in my example.
so `export default BaseComponent.extend({ name: 'Component', ...})` seems to duplicate the `watch` object instead of "merging" it - there is now one in the `BaseComponent` (where it is implemented initially) and one in the `Component` - and of course both react to prop-updates.
This seems to be a bug IMHO.

---

Using `vue-cli` with single file components.
I am setting a prop in one component via a method:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <other-component :my-object="myObject" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default (Vue as VueConstructor).extend({
    data() {
      return {
        myObject: null
      }
    },

    methods: {
      actionButtonClicked(action, ID) {
        console.log('actionButtonClicked');

        this.myObject = {
          action: action,
          ID: ID
        }
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

then I am watching the prop in the other component with a watcher - but watch gets called twice on every execution of the method.

```
<script>

  export default (Vue as VueConstructor<Vue>).extend({
    /* ... */
    props: {
      myObject: {
      type: Object,
      default: null
    },

    watch: {
      'myObject.ID'(value, oldValue) {
        console.log('watcher executed');
      }
    }

    /* ... */
  });

</script>
```

so in the console i get the output:

```
actionButtonClicked
watcher executed
watcher executed
```

.. every time the method gets called.

I already tried all different variants of watchers - for example with `deep: true` + `handler`. but this all didn't change anything about the watcher being called twice.

Comment: Is there a difference between `value` and `oldValue` on the consecutive executions of watch?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty no, they are the same. the first is `<ID>`, `null` **twice** - then it's `<ID>`, `<old ID>` **twice** .. and so on.

Comment: Without seeing more of your implementation I might suggest you use rely on `debounce` to only execute the watch function once.  Do you use the lodash in your project, it has an implementation of debounce?  But better to figure out why `actionButtonClicked` is being executed twice.  Have you mistakenly added an event handler more than once?  Regardless, sometimes a technique I use when trying to debug issues with methods being executed more than once, is as the very first line try `console.log(new Error().stack)` to see if that indicates any differences between the calls

Comment: Could you share the code where you call your method?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty it's exactly the other way round: the watcher is executed twice - the method is only executed once - so there are no problems with events or stuff like this.

Comment: @Ricky unfortunately the components are much much more complex - but I think I shared the relevant parts. the method is called by a simple click event - and this method only gets called once - so there shouldn't be any problem in this part of the implementation.

Comment: There's not enough information, the watcher is fine. Either the method is called twice, the object is mutated elsewhere, or the component is created twice.

Comment: @Ricky thank you for your comments. The method isn't called twice, otherwise it would trigger the console output of `actionButtonClicked` twice. I introduced a completely new object, so this shouldn't be mutated anywhere else. And I just checked if the component is created more than once - but that's also not the case. 
I know it's very strange - but there must be something else going on.

Comment: @Ricky I just found out that the reason for the strange behavior was, that the component extends a base-component where the watcher is implemented. 
so the watcher seems to be duplicated by the `.extend(...)` method. 
I am not completely sure, but IMHO this seems like a bug of the extend method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My watcher was duplicated because I was extending my `BaseComponent` in two ways:

- by the `extend()` method of the component itself
- by putting `extends: BaseComponent` into the options of the "outer" component

I thought you needed to use both pieces of code to extend another component, but apparently this is wrong and can lead to bad side effects.

Answer (score 39):

In my case, I have the "watch" in a component and use the component twice on the page, so the "watch" is being registered twice.

Hopefully, it'll help somebody that has the same problem.

Comment: I don't know why someone dislikes my comment. It's merely a sharing just in case someone else has the same situation.

Comment: actually this is my exact same problem too

Comment: I think I moved the watched filed to the store, and moved the "watch" to a root component.

Comment: Is the watching mutating something outside of the component? Otherwise I don't see how this would make any sense. You should be able to have watchers in a component, use the component repeatedly, and the watcher only fires for the instance of the component that's being changed.

Comment: @DeyiKong That's why it's not recommended to mutate anything outside of your component. Just emit the new values and let the instance be in charge of mutating data.

Comment: ...which, I guess, is what you said you did to solve the issue :)

Comment: geez, obvious... spent 2hours on this and forgot that I was using  it twice...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your component tree using a tool like the vue console or manually follow the list of imported components on your page in order to ensure no component is inadvertently imported twice.

I had a modal in the default layout, but wanted to display the modal body/main contents on a certain page (i.e without being triggered in a modal). I ended up importing both, and vue correctly treated them as separate instances. Which meant weird behavior like the modal taking two clicks to disappear, and of course, their watchers getting called twice